# Will 1 Inch sensor give same exposure at same aperture and ISO settings compared to APS-C sensor?

Tags: exposure, sensor, aps-c, wide-aperture

I know that APS-C is many times bigger than 1 inch and it dramatically effects shallow depth of field. But I was wondering if I'll shoot night city for example with same aperture and ISO setting on both 1 inch and APS-C would 1 inch sensor shot look underexposed?